# Complex number division by polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is it possible to divide complex number with another number? I mean I need to do polynomial division with complex number by another number. For example,
$2+6i/ x^2+1$.

Comment: A polynomial is not a number.

Comment: I already meantion my problem.I mean that is it possible to divide?

Comment: You mean ${\frac{2}{x^2+1}+i\frac{6}{x^2+1}}$ ?

Comment: The division algorithm works for any polynomial ring over a field.

Comment: please explain.It helps a lot for begineer

Comment: Given the nature of your question, I think you should convert your denominator (which you need to rewrite for parsing as mentioned above) to s*(exp(t)) along the lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula   .  Where s and t are determined by your complex terms.  Then division is pretty obvious.  Inserting x+iy in the denominator as a polynomial is harder to handle.